# Is there any way to print pandas dataframe in textwise coloring?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

To be simple, I try to print a text using pandas dataframe with different colors in textwise, not cellwise.

It means just like below.

```
Textwise : | a(red)b(blue)c(green) |

Cellwise : | abc (red) | abc (blue) | abc(green)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can embed the html code into the cell text, and render in jupyter notebook with `df.style`:

```
# data with embedded HTML code
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['<span style="color:red">a</span><span style="color:blue">b</span><span style="color:green">c</span>']})

# render with Jupyter notebook
df.style
```

Output:

[image]